# Php Script Debugging , Syntax Errors

Tags: php

I am starting my php development for first time after gaining some experice. And coded a script on my freinds demand.

Here is script But i am not able to Run it on my server.

```
<?php

  include("geoip.inc");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

// Country name is not used so commented
// Get Country Name based on source IP
//$country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "$ip");
$real=false;
geoip_close($gi);

{if ($_SERVER[’HTTP_USER_AGENT’]!= “Googlebot”)
{if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") 
  {setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+315360000); 
  if ($country_code="US")
{
    if(preg_match("/google\.com(.+?)sa=(.+?)/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    include_once("Biggenius.htm");
    else
    $real=True;
};
else
$real=True;

};

}
else
$real=True;};

if ($real==True)
 include_once(Biggenius1.htm);
?php>
```

This script is not running, also i would like to learn . How to code it in much simpler way. Any alternative and efficient style of coding this?

Some people pointed out error, but i am still not able to work it out.
Please post entire code without error. Instead of posting just error. 
Regards

Comment: Add this line to the start of the script, just after the opening `<?php`: `error_reporting(-1);` This will show all errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: Well, look at the line numbers and see if you can find these errors on or around these lines :)

Answer (score 0):

You have three occurences of:

```
};
```

Which you need to change to:

```
}
```

And there could be more errors in your script, errors messages could help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move the brackets:

```
if ($_SERVER[’HTTP_USER_AGENT’] !=  “Googlebot”) { 
    //Do stuff
}
```

The brackets go after the `if` condition, so `if (condition) { code }`. You did this correctly in a number of places but not everywhere. See the errors PHP outputs for the specific line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You conditional blocks should like `{ //code }` rather than `{ //code };`
Also the closing tag `?php>` is not valid. It's `?>` if it's a pure php file you can omit the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rife with syntax errors! Here's the cleaned up version.

```
<?php

  include("geoip.inc");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

// Country name is not used so commented
// Get Country Name based on source IP
//$country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "$ip");
$real=false;
geoip_close($gi);

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']!= 'Googlebot') {
    if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes")  {
        setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+315360000); 
        if ($country_code="US") {
            if(preg_match("/google\.com(.+?)sa=(.+?)/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
                include_once("Biggenius.htm");
            } else {
                $real = true;
            }
        } else {
            $real = true;
        }
    }
} else {
    $real = true;
}

if ($real) {
    include_once('Biggenius1.htm');
}

?>
```

Comment: @LarryBailey, can you elaborate, perhaps post some useful error messages?

Comment: I am trying to "emulate" new user to my site. Using hidemyass.